# PyQt Automatically resize widget in scroll area

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I am trying to create a window with a scroll area with widgets. This works. I tried to add a simple filter function to this window. This also works. The only problem is that the widgets inside the scroll area don't keep their size, when some are hidden. Is there a way to make sure the widgets in the scroll area maintain their size?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


class test(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.label_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_widget.setLayout(self.label_layout)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label_widget)

        self.filter_field = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.label_layout.addWidget(self.filter_field)

        self.refresh_pbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Refresh")
        self.label_layout.addWidget(self.refresh_pbutton)

        self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        self.refresh_pbutton.clicked.connect(self.refresh)
        self.filter_field.textChanged.connect(self.filter)

        self.populate()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def populate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widgets = []
        self.scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scroll_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")
        self.scroll_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)

        for i in range(1, 11):
            widget = smallWidget(str(i))
            self.widgets.append(widget)
            self.scroll_layout.addWidget(widget)

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
        self.filter_field.setText("")

    def refresh(self):
        self.populate()

    def filter(self):
        filter_text = str(self.filter_field.text())
        for widget in self.widgets:
            if filter_text in widget.name:
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()

class smallWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(smallWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.name)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.name_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    a = test()
    a.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the widgets directly to scroll_layout but create another layout, and in that layout add the widgets and use `addStretch()` so that it does not occupy the height of the first layout but the necessary one.

```
def populate(self):
    self.widgets = []
    self.scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scroll_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")
    self.scroll_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)

    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # <---
    self.scroll_layout.addLayout(lay) # <---
    self.scroll_layout.addStretch() # <---

    for i in range(1, 11):
        widget = smallWidget(str(i))
        self.widgets.append(widget)
        lay.addWidget(widget) # <---

    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
```

**Update:**

If you want the size of `scroll_widget` to be adjusted you must call `adjustSize()` an instant later with a `QTimer` since the geometry changes are not applied instantly

```
def filter(self, text):
    for widget in self.widgets:
        widget.setVisible(text in widget.name)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.scroll_widget.adjustSize)
```

Comment: Ok. This works. self.scroll_widget still always stays the same size. Is there a way to make it (the red part) actually resize to the fit the 2 widgets? This way the scroll bar would also disappear when something is being filtered.

Comment: @Daniel 
I have already updated the answer (note that I have changed your code to make it more elegant), if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. :)

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for!